# Runtime Error: vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, runtime-error

So, I wrote this code:

```
int main()
{
int max;
cin >> max;

vector<int> nums;
for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
{
    nums.push_back(i);
}

for (int i = 2; i <= max/10; i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j <= max; j += i)
    {
        nums[j - 2] = nums.back(); // problem maybe here
        nums.pop_back();
    }
}

for (int x : nums)
{
    cout << x << "\n";
}
}
```

I get runtime error after entering value of max. I included iostream, string, vector, algorithm, cmath and using namespace std. I don't have an idea where is the problem.

Comment: "I included iostream, string, vector, algorithm, cmath and using namespace std." - how could that *possibly* be relevant to a runtime error? BTW, just think about what your program does. You **are** indexing it out of bounds. (Oh, and for the love of goodness, **use a debugger.**)

Comment: The inner loop removes items from the vector, but you still loop through it as it would have all items inserted in the first initialization loop.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `int` as the index type for `std::vector`.  `std::vector` supplies the type `size_type` which is used for its indices and size.  Just think about what a signed -- e.g. `int` -- index type means.  It means that negative indices are valid, but what does a negative index into a container mean?

Comment: Index is not negative. j=i and i=2 and 2-2 is 0 so index is 0.

Comment: BTW debugger tells me there is a problem on the line I commented. I'm new to programming and I would really appreciate help.

Comment: `.pop_back()` changes the size of the `vector`, hence the iteration from `2` to `max` will no longer be valid. The index operator `[]` will access the `vector` out of range (as you see) at some point once `j-2` is greater that the number of elements in the `vector`.

Comment: Try printing `j - 2` and `nums.size()` in the inner loop, and you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put various statements of

```
cout << "vector size is " << nums.size() << '\n';
```

into your code and possibly see what `j` is during your loop too.

You will then see where your subscript is running out of range. Note that everytime you do `nums.pop_back()` your are reducing the size of your vector by 1. And that happens in your inner-loop.